# How to handle the "ALL" using SQL query inside SPRING REST API?

Tags: java, android, sql, spring, rest

I'am building REST API to work with Android application. Android app has dropdowns (spinners) and datepickers allowing to choose parameters. Request are processed and changed to SQL (Oracle 11g) querys using @Query (...) annotation.

Problem starts when I want to hendle 'ALL' option (take all options).

REST API is JAVA Spring Boot and Hibernate. Android app sends request with parameters and response is plain JSON. If user selects 'ALL' param value is 999999 (it may be changed if needed).

So it looks like: myurl/getinfo/2/4/999999/56

I tryied many options: ?1 to send all conditions, used % as param value, writen methods to build native query as String and send using PreparedStatement. Nothing works. Always errors.

Can someone enlighten me as it should generally look like? How to handle 'ALL' send as parameter and how to process it by Java Spring REST?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be Criteria Api is better for this- you will get program way to manage restriction (where clause in sql).
look to turorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I read tutorial and I was able to write code I was needed. Again thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Criteria API is a good option to deal with this problem (construct query without specific columns when you don't wont to filter by it - this should be handled in your Java code).

But if you want to stay with @Query, you can delegate computing of this condition to database, by creating query similar to this:

```
where (999999 = ?1 or field1 = ?1) and (999999 = ?2 or field2 = ?2)
```

This will cause query field1 = :param1 to compute only when :param1 is not 999999.